# What is the best way to bring down a web application for a quick modification in WebSphere AS?

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere

While making some small changes to a Web application which is deployed in a WebSphere AS, we want to bring the application down with a static *Under Construction* page. What is the best way to achieve this given that it should not be required to restart the AS. Something similar to an ASP.Net App_Offline.htm like solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org) as proxy server in front of WAS with help of [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) (ignore the Tomcat part, it'll work just fine, WAS uses a fork of Tomcat onder the covers) and provide that static *Under Construction* page as 404/503 error page in Apache HTTPD configuration.

Comment: while Apache HTTPD and mod_jk likely will work, IBM HTTP Server and Websphere Plugin would be the correct tooling... (yes, right, it's just a renamed Apache and a renamed mod_jk, I know I know... but at least it's supported and it comes in the box with most of editions of WAS)